# How to use UriTemplate?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have below OperationContract in my WCF web service.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/publisheddata/{number}/{*publication}")]
Message GetPublished(String number, String publication);

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/unpublisheddata/{number}/{*publication}")]
Message GetUnPublished(String number, String publication);
```

I want to call one common method for above both OperationContract, means in the Service implementation code I will call the Stored Procedure on the basis UriTemplate called, I know i can easily do by adding extra attribute in above url, I don't want to ask user to put it from the url.

Here I want to write condition on the basis of UriTemplate called, so my above code become as below:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/publisheddata/{number}/{*publication}")]
Message GetData(String number, String publication);

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/unpublisheddata/{number}/{*publication}")]
Message GetData(String number, String publication);
```

In my Service implementation, I want to check **if unpublisheddata then GetUnPublished else if publisheddata then GetPublisheddata**

Is it possible or suggest better ways to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

firstly, -probably- you'll get exception because of your method names. you can't use same method names like yours, but you can use OperationContract property "Name"

```
[OperationContract(Name="GetPublished")]
Message GetData(String number, String publication);

[OperationContract(Name="GetUnPublished")]
Message GetData(String number, String publication);
```

if you prefer single method, you can modify your method like this

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{publicationType}/{number}/{*publication}")]
Message GetData(string publicationType, string number, string publication);
```

and in your method you check "publicationType" parameter and do your logic

Comment: ok...how can I write else if condition in service implementation class where I will be differenciating between GetPublished and GetUnPublished. I don't want to give option to user to enter the method they want to enter so "NO" for second option which is easy to implement. Please suggest on first option

Answer (score 0):

if I understand truly, you want provide access only single method. I'm using a structure like this in my project

```
 [WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate ="/customers", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json), Description("Save a customer information")]
 OperationResult CustomerSave(Request<Customer> customerRequest);
```

and also I have 2 different methods -not show in WCF interface / contract- that names "Create" and "Update"

in my wcf method (CustomerSave), I'm doing process like this

```
if(customerRequest.Id != Guid.Empty)
{
    Update(customerRequest);
}
else
{
   Create(customerRequest);
}
```

and my users can not see Create / Update methods

Comment: Still how I am going to differenciate between GetPublished and GetUnPublished on service implementation class